# Google Cloud Storage stores data that was deleted

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I deleted a bucket in Cloud Storage and now I should only have two buckets left (see screenshot from dashboard below). However, if I go to Metrics explorer it still says 5GB of data is still stored in that bucket (see screenshot). Why is that and how can I delete it?
[image: buckets]
[image: storage]

Answer (score 1):

The value is updated once per day:

> Total size of all objects in the bucket, grouped by storage class.
> This value is measured once per day, and there might be a delay after
> measuring before the value becomes available in Cloud Monitoring.

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#storage/storage/total_bytes)

Comment: I thought it there would be a delay, so I waited 2 days before posting the question. The value is still the same. Is it possible that it takes more time to update the value? I am getting billed, so that's why it's an issue.

Comment: @Nina - Two days is enough - consider opening a Cloud Billing support ticket with details. However, do not delete artifact buckets. Those are important for your services such as App Engine, Cloud Run, Functions, Cloud Build, etc. At roughly two pennies per GB per month ...